# Does Running Node Locally Differ From Installing Node on the Web Server?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I'm wondering in principle how node.js works on a website that's running node code. I'm new to programming but I did manage to get node installed to practice with Angular and some Nodeschool stuff, however I don't think this is actually the whole story because the web server needs to have node and npm (maybe nvm) all installed in order to actually use any node code. Or am I misunderstanding how node works?

I guess I'm really looking for an understanding of the whole application of the node framework; what am I actually doing by running a practice program like the "Tour of Heros" Angular tutorial on my local machine, just testing it locally right? Because if I actually wanted it on my website I'd need to install node there and then run the framework on the server, from what I can gather...

Thanks for your time! I hope I made my confusion clear enough.

[Angular tutorial by Google "Tour of Heroes"](https://angular.io/tutorial)

Comment: to answer the question in the title ... there is no difference ... to answer only question in the body ... yes, you misundertand node.js if you think you need to compile anything ... node doesn't create javascript code ... node IS javascript code - do you know any other server side languages, such as PHP? Think of node.js as being a server side language, because ... it is

Comment: I think this question is too broad. I suggest you look up how web applications, and client-server architecture works in general, because this is a vastly bigger topic than what could be reasonably put in an answer. This will be the background to NodeJS itself - once you understand the theory, then NodeJS is not too complex to understand the idea of. It does what other normal server languages do but it has it's own pros and cons to consider.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node and JavaScript are different. Node provides a runtime environment enables JavaScript code to be executed outside browser. It provides various native libraries and event loop allowing main thread of execution to perform asynchronous operations.

Comment: Thanks, the context I've been missing while taking the beginning steps learning this framework is that the work I've done installing Node and updating the version using npm and nvm, running stuff on the command line... that's all just for the machine I'm on and if I actually use this—as in praxis, not in a tutorial—it's got to be installed on the web server machine.